# refresh web in django

Tags: python, django

I have a question, how do I refresh the page where I am currently in django? I am new with all this, add a favorite button, but I am doing a redirect to a page, it is wrong, since I only need the page where I am currently to be refreshed, could someone help me?

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the page? What about the page will change?

Comment: change one of the icons, I do a redirect('store') but if I'm on page 3 it returns me to the beginning

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there is no way to do a return redirect( current page ) or something like that?

Comment: greeted, I just had to do a redirect to a request.META.get['HTTP_REFERER']

Answer (score 0):

greeted, I just had to do a redirect to a `request.META.get['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).